# extract lines between same keyword that match a pattern

Tags: sed

Need to match a pattern which is unique across the file but need to print lines between two markers, where a pattern is matched.

My file looks like this.

```
echo "Start 2A25.20090401.64809.7.HDF 6420 6751"
echo "dimensions 9249 49"
echo "New Cell"
grep "6542,06" ../TextFilesDir/out.2A25.20090401.64809.7.HDF.txt.text = 20.09 8.07334 74.6131 170 0 6 6
grep "6542,07" ../TextFilesDir/out.2A25.20090401.64809.7.HDF.txt.text = 32.25 8.11139 74.6406  210 3.66764
grep "6543,06" ../TextFilesDir/out.2A25.20090401.64809.7.HDF.txt.text = 33.28 8.05147 74.6431  210 0.84248
grep "6543,07" ../TextFilesDir/out.2A25.20090401.64809.7.HDF.txt.text = 43.38 8.08952 74.6707  210 20.3994
grep "6543,08" ../TextFilesDir/out.2A25.20090401.64809.7.HDF.txt.text = 24.22 8.12717 74.6979  210 1.21783
grep "6544,06" ../TextFilesDir/out.2A25.20090401.64809.7.HDF.txt.text = 35.81 8.02963 74.6732  210 6.31353
grep "6544,07" ../TextFilesDir/out.2A25.20090401.64809.7.HDF.txt.text = 41.58 8.06767 74.7007  200 14.5371
grep "6545,06" ../TextFilesDir/out.2A25.20090401.64809.7.HDF.txt.text = 36.3 8.00776 74.7033  120 6.13395
grep "6545,07" ../TextFilesDir/out.2A25.20090401.64809.7.HDF.txt.text = 31.57 8.0458 74.7308  210 4.22794
grep "6546,06" ../TextFilesDir/out.2A25.20090401.64809.7.HDF.txt.text = 28.49 7.98589 74.7333  292 2.64533
echo "New Cell"
grep "6562,21" ../TextFilesDir/out.2A25.20090401.64809.7.HDF.txt.text = 26.74 8.19021 75.6125 210 0.61061 9 9
grep "6563,20" ../TextFilesDir/out.2A25.20090401.64809.7.HDF.txt.text = 26.35 8.13187 75.6167  210 1.0852
grep "6563,21" ../TextFilesDir/out.2A25.20090401.64809.7.HDF.txt.text = 42.51 8.16825 75.6426  200 13.5489
grep "6563,22" ../TextFilesDir/out.2A25.20090401.64809.7.HDF.txt.text = 25.82 8.20457 75.6684  210 0.615512
grep "6564,20" ../TextFilesDir/out.2A25.20090401.64809.7.HDF.txt.text = 23.08 8.10994 75.6467  272 0.613962
grep "6564,21" ../TextFilesDir/out.2A25.20090401.64809.7.HDF.txt.text = 46.55 8.14632 75.6726  200 17.1675
grep "6564,22" ../TextFilesDir/out.2A25.20090401.64809.7.HDF.txt.text = 36.89 8.18263 75.6984  200 3.10095
grep "6565,21" ../TextFilesDir/out.2A25.20090401.64809.7.HDF.txt.text = 31.61 8.12436 75.7026  200 2.52639
grep "6565,22" ../TextFilesDir/out.2A25.20090401.64809.7.HDF.txt.text = 28.85 8.16067 75.7284  120 0.945648
echo "New Cell"
```

I need sed to match pattern and print all the lines in the cell where pattern matched.
For e.g. for "6545,06" as pattern I need all the lines that are between "New Cell" boundaries where the pattern matched, for this pattern need output as

```
grep "6542,06" ../TextFilesDir/out.2A25.20090401.64809.7.HDF.txt.text = 20.09 8.07334 74.6131 170 0 6 6
grep "6542,07" ../TextFilesDir/out.2A25.20090401.64809.7.HDF.txt.text = 32.25 8.11139 74.6406  210 3.66764
grep "6543,06" ../TextFilesDir/out.2A25.20090401.64809.7.HDF.txt.text = 33.28 8.05147 74.6431  210 0.84248
grep "6543,07" ../TextFilesDir/out.2A25.20090401.64809.7.HDF.txt.text = 43.38 8.08952 74.6707  210 20.3994
grep "6543,08" ../TextFilesDir/out.2A25.20090401.64809.7.HDF.txt.text = 24.22 8.12717 74.6979  210 1.21783
grep "6544,06" ../TextFilesDir/out.2A25.20090401.64809.7.HDF.txt.text = 35.81 8.02963 74.6732  210 6.31353
grep "6544,07" ../TextFilesDir/out.2A25.20090401.64809.7.HDF.txt.text = 41.58 8.06767 74.7007  200 14.5371
grep "6545,06" ../TextFilesDir/out.2A25.20090401.64809.7.HDF.txt.text = 36.3 8.00776 74.7033  120 6.13395
grep "6545,07" ../TextFilesDir/out.2A25.20090401.64809.7.HDF.txt.text = 31.57 8.0458 74.7308  210 4.22794
grep "6546,06" ../TextFilesDir/out.2A25.20090401.64809.7.HDF.txt.text = 28.49 7.98589 74.7333  292 2.64533
```

Unfortunately begin and end boundaries are the same. 
Would be grateful if I can get a sed script to do this.

Comment: What regex did you use?

Comment: I tried few examples where the keywords are different but in my case keyword (New Cell) is the same . I tried sed examples but it did not work in my case

Comment: It is the rule on this site that you show us first what you tried. Based on that, we can jump in and clarify hings for you. So please, show us what you tried and did not work.

Comment: sed -e '1,/6544,06/d' -e '/New Cell/,$d' CSR.WoSpix.apr2009.sh 
grep "6544,07" ../TextFilesDir/out.2A25.20090401.64809.7.HDF.txt.text = 41.58 8.06767 74.7007  200 14.5371
grep "6545,06" ../TextFilesDir/out.2A25.20090401.64809.7.HDF.txt.text = 36.3 8.00776 74.7033  120 6.13395
grep "6545,07" ../TextFilesDir/out.2A25.20090401.64809.7.HDF.txt.text = 31.57 8.0458 74.7308  210 4.22794
grep "6546,06" ../TextFilesDir/out.2A25.20090401.64809.7.HDF.txt.text = 28.49 7.98589 74.7333  292 2.64533

Comment: this is printing lines below the pattern (6544,06). Not above and i wish to retain New cell in the output which is not happening

Answer (score 0):

I do not have `sed` right now, but the following regex extracts exactly what you want (if I understood it correctly):

```
echo "New Cell"\s*(.*?"6542,06".*?)\s*echo "New Cell"
```

You can extract only the "grep" lines using `\1`.

Replace the `"6542,06"` part in the regex for other sub-strings to be found.

I tested the regex [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/y1HfP2/1).

Comment: thanks. I will try to use this regex in sed and update you.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/New Cell/ba;H;$!d;:a;x;/6546,06/s/.//p;z;x;d' file
```

Gather up lines following a line containing `New Cell` in the hold space (HS).

If encountering another line containing `New Cell` or the the end of the file is reached, check the collection for the required string (`6546,06` in the example above), and print the collection less the first character which will be an introduced newline.

Regardless of a match, empty the HS and repeat.